# Blender 2.8 VSE "No Items available" when adding the scene to the sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]

Hi,
I am learning how to use the VSE, how i can add my 3d scene (collection1) to the sequencer ? (I've deleted the defaut scene and create a new one )

EDIT : Ok,i have to save 2 times the same project ( test1.blend and test2.blend for exemple ) Then, File/Append and select the first blend file, navigate into the scene folder, and select my scene.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a scene strip referring to the same scene as you're currently in. So make a new scene/or a copy and this one you'll be able to add.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but like i said, it's already a complete new scene and it doesn't work. In Blender 2.79 it's very easy but with the 2.8 version, i'm stuck

Comment: i faced same problem and just struggled to create two different scenes, one for video editing and second for 3d, and it finaly worked.

Answer (score 0):

Up until 2.79 we could add the current scene to the VSE, 2.80+ does not allow this anymore.

One blend file can contain [multiple scenes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/scene/introduction.html), you can also save each scene in a different file and link each scene into the "final mix" file.

I would suggest adding a new scene to the file you are working on that is specifically for use in the VSE and adding a strip for the other scene that is in the same file.